# The Marine Jungle of More Than Just Angiosperms

Tags: science-based, flora, alternate-earth, adaptability

Recently, I asked whether or not the other plant groups besides the angiosperms could evolve to adapt to being submerged under salty ocean water 24/7.  While marine conifers, ginkgoes, cycads, ferns, horsetails, lycopods, liverworts and mosses are not possible on Earth, in an alternate Earth, they could have the opportunity.

So in an alternate Earth, the world's shallow waters are green with forests as complex as our kelp forests, if not more so.  But plants being plants, their diversity raises some concerns.  In marine jungles like this, what sorts of changes would the conifers, ginkgoes, cycads, ferns, horestails, lycopods, liverworts and mosses need to adapt to life in salty ocean water?

Comment: They would have to adapt to become algae-like. Algae have been at it for billions of years, they have marine photosynthesising all figured out.

Comment: @Renan  Tell that to the mangroves and the seagrasses.

Comment: Any particular reason I'm seeing 2 close options?

Comment: to be clear are you talking about surviving in fresh water or salt water. because there are lots of fresh water plants, but adapting to salt water is nearly impossible for vascular plants.

Comment: @John  Salt, and tell that to the mangroves and the seagrasses.

Comment: Underwater trees need not bear weight, so expect them to lose the habit of spending resources on wood.

Comment: You're seeing close votes because you're asking about a vast range of different plants in one question. Trees are a long way from moss.

Comment: Mangroves may be halophytes, but _underwater_ trees they are not. That just seems to leave you with seagrasses, and they're quite thoroughly un-treelike.

Comment: @AntonSherwood expect them to lose it fairly promptly; waves and currents are a lot stronger than storm winds, and tall, strong, inflexible trunks would be a liability. Kelp forests are filled with things that are well adapted to their environment, and aren't particularly tree-like...

Comment: http://www.madsci.org/posts/archives/2002-12/1039406639.Bt.r.html